# Intel MKL: link to PARDISO

Tags: fortran, intel, intel-mkl, stdcall, pardiso

setup:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Intel Parallel Studio 2018
- Intel Fortran Compiler Classic

VS solution:

- Project A, contains a subroutine "1" which calls MKL Pardiso
- Project B, a unit test project that calls subroutine "1"

Solution builds fine in Debug/64-bit, but Project B has a linker error in Debug/x86:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PARDISO@68 referenced in function "1"
```

I reference all of the MKL libs in Project B, for both platforms.

Question: what am I missing?

Comment: You should show your code. This looks lime some STDCALL issue. You may want check your call convention directives.

Comment: Why should the code be different between the 64 and 32-bit platform?

Comment: Because STDCALL only applies to 32bit. And only to MS Windows.

Comment: You are right. Setting the calling convention to Default in the project properties fixes the linker error. What is the general guideline about this? Should I leave it to Default for x64 as well?

Comment: It makes no difference for 64bit. In 32bit you must keep it consistent with the code you call.